# yield to a block using rr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rr

I'm trying to test the following code using `rr`:

```
response = RestClient.get(url, {:params => params}){|response, request, result| response }
```

In vanilla `rspec`, you would do something like this:

```
RestClient.should_receive(:get).with(url, {:params => params}).and_yield(response, request, result)
```

How would I do the same with `rr`?

Setup:

```
let(:url) { "http://localhost/" }
let(:params) { {:item_id => 1234, :n => 5} }
let(:response) { Object.new }
let(:request) { Object.new }
let(:result) { Object.new }
```

I've tried a bunch of variations on:

```
mock(RestClient).get(url, {:params => params}) { response, request, result }
```

and

```
mock(RestClient).get(url, {:params => params}, &proc/lambda{}).return(result)
```

and

```
mock(RestClient).get(url, {:params => params}).yields(response, request, result)
```

and

```
mock(RestClient).get(url, {:params => params}).returns do |proc_as_block|
  response
end
```

but none of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it.  This pull request helped: https://github.com/btakita/rr/pull/82

```
mock(RestClient).get(url, {:params => params}).yields(response, request, result) { response }
```

Comment: Thx, you helped with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19201353/449531), another example of using rr yields.